# How to run the meteor project which git cloned from the Github in different OS

Tags: meteor, git-clone

I've created a meteor project in my Windows system,then it be pushed to my Git repository.

Now I need to git clone to my Mac system and run it, but when I CD into the project folder and use "meteor" order in terminal line, It shows: "you need to creat APP ...", why? what should I do to run the project in my Mac system?

Many thanks~~~

Comment: Did you add the `.meteor` directory to your repository?

Comment: Yes,`.meteor` folder been added to my repository. but there is not `local` folder in the `.meteor` on my repository.

Comment: No need to commit `local`. Can you edit your post to include the `.meteor` directory listing and the actual message you are getting?

Comment: Many thanks~~~, It's an mistake and be fixed, there is sub folder on the in which my app created, originally, my `meteor` order ran in an wrong path, anyhow, thanks for your kindly answer.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried following the [tutorial](https://www.meteor.com/tutorials/blaze/creating-an-app)?

I think `meteor create` is what you need.